# I can't send notification to firebase from Postman

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I try send notification frpom Postman to Firebase

[image]

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "AAAAelYayDs:AP....",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

but I get response with text, just - `to`

I read that `to` - it is DEVICE_ID. But where I get this id? and what if I want send message to all devices?

[image]

Comment: what is the status code in postman after sending notification?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to hint that you're posting to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, which is the legacy FCM endpoint that [expects messages to have a `to` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices_2).

The new `token` property is only accepted by the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1` endpoint.